# How to apply operation for the first ng-model of same model name

Tags: angularjs

I have 2 radio buttons of the same ng-model now I want to make textbox disabling and enabling on based on first radio button clicking. How to get the individual status of first radio button to enable my text box

`<div style="display: flex; padding: 20px 0px 0px 12px;">
        <input type="radio" name="dailyRadio" ng-model="remind.daily" value="Every">
        <p id="type-recurrence">Every</p>
        <input type="text" id="days" ng-model="remind.dailyDays" ng-           disabled="!remind.daily">
    </div>
<div style="display: flex; padding: 8px 0px 0px 12px;">
  <input type="radio" name="dailyRadio" ng-model="remind.daily"   value="EveryweekDays">
    <p id="type-recurrence">Every WeekDays</p>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have created a plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/6zrIOUwRh7IczufnMGa6?p=preview

html:

```
  <body ng-controller="radioController">

    <div style="display: flex; padding: 20px 0px 0px 12px;">
        <input type="radio" name="dailyRadio" ng-model="remind.daily" value="Every" ng-click="getRadioValue()">
        <p id="type-recurrence">Every</p>
        <input type="text" id="days" ng-model="remind.dailyDays" ng-disabled="!flag">
    </div>
    <div style="display: flex; padding: 8px 0px 0px 12px;">
  <input type="radio" name="dailyRadio" ng-model="remind.daily"   value="EveryweekDays" ng-click="getRadioValue()">
    <p id="type-recurrence">Every WeekDays</p>
</div>
  </body>
```

js:

```
var APP = angular.module("APP",[]);

APP.controller("radioController", function($scope){

  $scope.remind = {};


  $scope.getRadioValue = function(){

    if($scope.remind.daily == "Every"){
    $scope.flag = true;
    }
    else {
      $scope.flag = false;
    }

  }

})
```

hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

First of all the `ng-model` (confirmed) set for the radio button should have a boolean value, and then you can directly use that model for `ng-disabled` directive of your text field.

```
//controller
function Controller($scope){
     $scope.confirmed=true;
     ...
}

//html code
<div ng-app>
 <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="confirmed" ng-change="change()"/>
    <div>{{confirmed}}</div>
    <input type="text" id="days" ng-model="remind.dailyDays" ng-disabled="!confirmed">
 </div>
</div>
```

[Live Demo @ JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Q6WTb/117/)

Comment: but I want 2 ng-models of same name.if it was in ng-repeat I can get by 'remind.dailyDays[0]' but now it's not in that scenario to get that particular ng-model.

Comment: are you saying that there may be multiple input fields with different ng-model like `'remind.dailyDays[0]'` ... `'remind.dailyDays[n]'` and you would like to disable/enable whole set with one radio button ?

Comment: I want to disable one radio button which is coded in HTML with same model name

Comment: `ng-model` for radio button should contain  only boolean values, so if  your ng model data `remind.daily` is of boolean type, then your code will work as expected. so make sure whatever value your setting to radio button and for ng-disabled should be boolean value.

Comment: I understood what u were saying.it works in individual model case. but in my case all ng-model were same here.

Comment: hmm, so if you have found your solution, can we close this question

Comment: your welcome, now close this question by ticking against the answer which solved your problem. happy coding :)